# Searching Login with Ajax using a jquery event

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I want to search a Login using Ajax so i won't have to refresh the page and using a jquery event here is the code but it doesn't work :(

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#login").keyup(submitForm);

 });
function submitForm()
{
var xhr= new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange=function()
{

    if (xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200)
    {
        document.getElementById("zone").innerHTML=xhr.responseText;
    }
}
    var str="SearchLogin.php?login="+document.getElementById("login").value;

xhr.open("GET",str,true);
xhr.send();
}
```

appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

You have a very strange mix of jQuery and JavaScript. If you are using jQuery it would be easier to stick with that. There is a jQuery AJAX function which might be easier than using the JavaScript function. See the documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

If I put your code into the jQuery function instead of using JavaScript AJAX:

```
function submitForm()
{
    $.ajax({
      url: "SearchLogin.php?login="+$('#login').attr('value'),
    }).done(function(response) { 
      $('#zone').innerHTML = response;
    });
}
```

Does that help clarify things somewhat?

Comment: it clarified and helped lots :))

Answer (score 1):

I would use the jquery $.ajax function instead:

```
function submitForm(){
    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'SearchLogin.php',
        data: {
            login: $('#login').val()
        }
    }).done(function(response){
        $('#zone').html(response);
    });
}
```

You can check the output by using `console.log(response)` with firebug within the .done function.  Firebug also proves useful because you can use the console to see if it found the page, if it posted successfully, if data was sent back, etc.  Just click the request and you can view all the details.  I would recommend testing it by echoing out 'Hello World' on your server side script just to see if the connection is working.